# Mapbox problem with creating PopUp for each cluster/marker with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a problem where I am fetching my data from my API using WordPress. I have multiple clusters/markers on my map. But I am not able to create for each location a PopUp marker with the data coming from the API. I am facing some scoping issue where I want to have one popup dynamically show the data based ont he clicked marker if that makes sense.

Is there a trick on how to solve this?

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import MapboxLanguage from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-language';
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';

(() => {
    const mapContainer = document.querySelector('[data-gewoon-wonen]');

    if (!mapContainer) {
        return;
    }

    mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.MAP_TOKEN_KEY;

    const center = [4.387733, 51.862419];

    const locations = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: []
    };

    apiFetch({ path: '/wp-json/wp/v2/map?_embed' }).then((maps) => {
        maps.forEach((item) => {
            const {
                id,
                title: { rendered: title },
                _embedded,
                acf
            } = item;

            const image =
                _embedded && _embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0]?.source_url;

            const {
                map_location_subtitle: subtitle,
                map_location_delivery: delivery,
                map_location_project: project,
                map_location_content: description,
                map_location_coordinates_lat: lat,
                map_location_coordinates_lng: lng,
                map_location_status: status,
                map_location_website: website
            } = acf;

            const getStatus = (currentStatus) => {
                let statusObj = {
                    bouwfase: 'marker-gray',
                    planfase: 'marker-bright-pink',
                    opgeleverd: 'marker-bright-blue',
                    default: ''
                };

                let icon = statusObj[currentStatus] || statusObj['default'];

                return icon;
            };

            const object = {
                type: 'Feature',
                properties: {
                    id,
                    status,
                    image,
                    icon: getStatus(status),
                    title,
                    subtitle,
                    project,
                    website,
                    delivery,
                    description
                },
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [lng, lat]
                }
            };

            locations.features.push(object);
        });
    });

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/theme/clcz9eocm000p14o3vh42tqfj',
        center,
        zoom: 10,
        minZoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 18,
        attributionControl: false,
        cooperativeGestures: true
    });

    map.addControl(
        new MapboxLanguage({
            defaultLanguage: 'mul'
        })
    );

    map.on('load', () => {
        // Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and
        // set the 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will
        // add the point_count property to your source data.
        map.addSource('locations', {
            type: 'geojson',
            // Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ locations
            // from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
            data: locations,
            cluster: true,
            clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
            clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'clusters',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'locations',
            filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
            paint: {
                // Use step expressions (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-step)
                // with three steps to implement three types of circles:
                //   * Blue, 20px circles when point count is less than 100
                //   * Yellow, 30px circles when point count is between 100 and 750
                //   * Pink, 40px circles when point count is greater than or equal to 750
                'circle-color': [
                    'step',
                    ['get', 'point_count'],
                    '#51bbd6',
                    100,
                    '#f1f075',
                    750,
                    '#f28cb1'
                ],
                'circle-radius': [
                    'step',
                    ['get', 'point_count'],
                    20,
                    100,
                    30,
                    750,
                    40
                ]
            }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'cluster-count',
            type: 'symbol',
            source: 'locations',
            filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
            layout: {
                'text-field': ['get', 'point_count_abbreviated'],
                'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                'text-size': 12
            }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'unclustered-point',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'locations',
            filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
            paint: {
                'circle-color': '#11b4da',
                'circle-radius': 4,
                'circle-stroke-width': 1,
                'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
            }
        });

        // inspect a cluster on click
        map.on('click', 'clusters', (e) => {
            const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
                layers: ['clusters']
            });
            const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
            map.getSource('locations').getClusterExpansionZoom(
                clusterId,
                (err, zoom) => {
                    if (err) return;

                    map.easeTo({
                        center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
                        zoom: zoom
                    });
                }
            );
        });

        // When a click event occurs on a feature in
        // the unclustered-point layer, open a popup at
        // the location of the feature, with
        // description HTML from its properties.
        map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', (e) => {
            const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
            const mag = e.features[0].properties.mag;
            const tsunami =
                e.features[0].properties.tsunami === 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';

            // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that
            // multiple copies of the feature are visible, the
            // popup appears over the copy being pointed to.
            while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
                coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
            }

            new mapboxgl.Popup()
                .setLngLat(coordinates)
                .setHTML(
                    `magnitude: ${mag}<br>Was there a tsunami?: ${tsunami}`
                )
                .addTo(map);
        });

        map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Seems like two problems: (A) a popup for each marker not working, and (B) a single common popup showing dynamic data not working. I presume (A) is supposed to occur on click of a marker, but... when is (B) supposed occur? In any case, you mention "cluster" in your post title. Is there something you desire to happen when a cluster is clicked (other than it exploding and showing markers)?

Comment: I have an app with map+clustering, but I use Leaflet. In any case, the concepts are the same. Another aspect is: If you desire a common element that will be "stable" and have dynamic content within based on users clicks, then I ask... do you have a sidebar or drawer for this (rather than relying on a map popup) ? For example, go to Google Maps, and their sidebars and drawers are not map popups, they are simply high-level UI elements in the app.

Comment: @MarsAndBack I have updated my code to a minimal working example with the multiple cluster locations based on my dynamic data. Now, I have this `locations.features.push(object);` line of code where I am pushing all the dynamic content. Now I want this data to be available for each cycle/popup. Instead it's showing only one right now. How can I get my dynamic data inside the popup now? Also console logging `locations.features` on click of each unclustered-point returns/fires an array of 10 items which is correct. But how to show the correct array item for each cluster?

Comment: Ok, looking at your code I see no click listener defined for individual map markers (aka "map points"); I would expect to see one inside the loop staring here: `maps.forEach((item) => {`, for example: `item.addEventListener('click', (event) => { // logic })`. Inside this click logic you would do things like... open a popup, update content in some other element (like a static popup), etc. In `event` you could grab the data you set on the item, or here is where you could do a dynamic API request too. I don't use mapbox, but I would expect to see this somewhere.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Well after taking 2 hours of break as you already now as a developer it seems like I have figured it out. Pretty lame... Inside the clicked "cluster" function it's returning the coordinates and all other data... ugh. It was there I have figure it out it works now.